# ListView still displaying deleted items

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a database, and a table (Access). I'm loading the table to my ListView

**The problem:**

I have items with the following IDs : `12, 18, 19, 25, 26`

If I decide to first delete the item with ID `18` and then `25`. The `18` will be deleted from the database whenever I call the function, but the ListView won't show that 18 got deleted until I did another delete operation (`25` in this case).

Here's my code:

```cs
try
{
    string selectedID = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;

    string databasePath = Application.StartupPath + databaseName;

    string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + databasePath;
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);

    con.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE ID = @ID");
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", selectedID);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    LoadList(false);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Erreur, veuillez contactez le développeur" + e.ToString());
}
```

And this is the code responsible for loading the list again (after deleting an item):

```cs
listView1.Items.Clear();
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
string databasePath = Application.StartupPath + databaseName;

string sql = "Select * from Table1";
OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection();
cnn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + databasePath;
cnn.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, cnn);
OleDbDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

int COUNT = 0;

if (firstTime)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        listView1.Columns.Add(Reader.GetName(i));
    }
}

while (Reader.Read())
{
    ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(Reader.GetInt32(0).ToString());
    lv.SubItems.Add(Reader.IsDBNull(1) ? null : Reader.GetString(1));
    lv.SubItems.Add(Reader.IsDBNull(2) ? null : Reader.GetString(2));
    lv.SubItems.Add(Reader.IsDBNull(3) ? null : Reader.GetString(3));

    lv.SubItems.Add(Reader.IsDBNull(4) ? null : Reader.GetString(4));
    lv.SubItems.Add(Reader.IsDBNull(5) ? null : Reader.GetInt32(5).ToString());

    lv.SubItems.Add(Reader.IsDBNull(6) ? null : Reader.GetString(6));

    lv.SubItems.Add(Reader.IsDBNull(7) ? null : Reader.GetString(7));

    lv.SubItems.Add(Reader.IsDBNull(8) ? null : Reader.GetString(8));

    lv.SubItems.Add(Reader.IsDBNull(9) ? null : Reader.GetString(9));
    lv.SubItems.Add(Reader.IsDBNull(10) ? null : Reader.GetString(10));
    lv.SubItems.Add(Reader.IsDBNull(11) ? null : Reader.GetString(11));

    listView1.Items.Add(lv);
}

Reader.Close();
cnn.Close();
```

**The expected behavior:**

I want for the item to be deleted in real time when I call the delete function.

Comment: What is the return value of `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` ?

Comment: @CaiusJard Strange. After you asked that, I went ahead and changed that line to `int returnedValue = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` and I also added a MessageBox to display that and it's now deleting when I close the MessageBox? Any explanations for this?

And to answer your question, the query  is returning 1. Like I said, when the first deletion occurs, and I check the database directly, I can see that it's working fine. It's just not reflecting in the ListView.

Comment: Use `listView1.Refresh()` at the end of loading code to force its redrawing.

Comment: @ɐsɹǝʌǝɔıʌ That didn't help. Only thing that's making it work, is if I show a MessageBox after the deletion.

Comment: You do clear the list, right?

Comment: (This life is so much easier with databainding..)

Comment: ... even more if you use a Control that supports DataBindings, as a DataGridView. Which would automate the whole thing -- This: `string databasePath = Application.StartupPath + databaseName;` is *terrible*.

Comment: @CaiusJard I do clear the list, yes.

Comment: @Jimi Could you please tell me why? I'm just trying to build a small tool but I'd still be interested in knowing what's the best practice here.

Comment: Read here: [Updating Data Sources with DataAdapters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters) + all the `DataAdapters and DataReaders` section you can see in the menu on the left of that page. -- When you have setup a DataAdapter correctly, you Add / Delete / Update everything in a single command. The internal procedure takes care of the precedence. The UI of bound Controls is updated automatically. -- You can use DataTables, of course, but I suggest to consider mini/micro-ORMs (e.g., Dapper)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm just trying to build a small tool but I'd still be interested in knowing what's the best practice here

I'm not sure that I'd classify Access as "best practice" anything, and the following method for data access is also a bit long in the tooth these days, but it's a better practice than what you're doing:

- Add a DataSet type of file to your project
- Open it, right click its surface, choose Add.. TableAdapter
- Fill in the connection string panel for your access DB
- Read carefully the massive messagebox about copying the file into your project and "information about controlling this behavior" - it's basically saying it will copy the db file into the project and then it will be copied to the `bin` folder when the project is built. This is important because your program will edit the db file in bin\debug, but most developers go looking in the wrong file (in the project) when assessing whether the app saved anything, and come complaining. Or they complain that their app doesn't save (it does, but the build proces overwrites the updated DB with a fresh one every time). Pay close attention
- Add a "query that returns rows", perhaps `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Id = @id`
- Finish the wizard, calling it FillById/GetDataById
- You end up with a Person datatable in your dataset
- You switch to your form
- You open the Data Sources window (View menu, Other Windows)
- You drag the Person node onto the form. A datagridview, bindingsource, tableadapter, navigator and dataset appear

That's pretty much it; you'd run the app, bash a person id in the box, hit fill, they appear in the grid, you can edit the details, and hit save. If you want to load more people/make the searching a bit more useful, you go back to the dataset, right click the tableadapter, add another query, maybe `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Name LIKE @name` and call it FillByName etc - then you can jiggle the code to use that one instead - you can run the app, put `J%` in the box, load everyone whose name starts with J, edit them, save them..